# Firebase redirect me when trying to access database from webbrowser

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-console

I'm trying to delete a collection using firebase via webbrowser. I sign in to firebase console and when I press database in project overview it redirect me just when database was loaded to firebase console overview.

How can I solve this issue and why is this happening? It's only happen to a single project, the other projects works fine.

Comment: This sounds like something you need to take up with google support. Are you able to delete the collection though the rest API?

Comment: Agreed with Garrett that this sounds like a support issue. But some hints: be sure to disable any extensions/plugins you may have in your browser, and check the JavaScript console of your browser for any relevant error messages.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen What do you mean with support issue? It's only one project that redirect me, I have a bunch of other projects that present the database correctly. Tried with Chrome, Firefox, Safari, same problem with this project on all browsers. Any other ideas? Also, how can I contact the support?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/support

Answer (score 0):

open firebase console, log in your email, click on the database, there will open your table over there. delete the node which you want to delete, simply click on the `'x'` button. It will not redirect you, log in properly.

Comment: Ok you missunderstood me. The problem I have is that the database isn't even presented. The moment firebase complete loading database, I get redirected to firebase console overview.